# Cannot find class [net.ab.cd.myProcessor.myProcessor] for bean with name 'myProcessor' nested exception is ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, gradle, apache-camel

I'm using apache camel to send/receive exchange properties in MyProcessor class which is implemented by Processor interface:

```
package net.ab.cd.myProcessor

public class MyProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        //logic to accept and send exchange properties
    }
}
```

My camel xml looks something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring- 
beans.xsd
                        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
                        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

<bean id="myProcessor" class="net.ab.cd.myProcessor.MyProcessor"/>

<camelContext id="mainContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="route1">
        <from uri="direct:start"/>
        <to uri="bean:myProcessor"/>
        <to uri="bean:varpop?method=moveToOutboundVariables(&apos;statusResponse&apos;)"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

I've built my class project such that it relocates my package using shadowJar:

```
group = "net.ab.cd"
shadowJar {
    relocate("${project.group}", "${project.group}.myProcessor.shadow") {
        exclude "${project.group}.myProcessor.*"
    }
}
```

But at the end I'm getting this error, and It's not able to find my class:
Cannot find class [net.ab.cd.myProcessor.MyProcessor] for bean with name 'myProcessor' nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException